# What are the references of this type of 2 dimensional Shallow Water Equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, resource-recommendations, continuum-mechanics

I'm reading the Wikipedia of Shallow Water Equations(SWEs) in 2 dimensional case.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations
I notice that the 2d case in the page was stated as:

[image]

But there is no references of this type SWEs. Can anyone provide me with some references? Textbooks or papers are OK!

Especially I'd like to know it is possible to just simply write the viscous drag terms as $-ku$ and $-kv$? Is there any more assumptions on this model? Since in one dimensional case, the viscous drag term is often written as $-k\frac{u^2}{h},$ which is proportional to quadratic term of $u$ and inversely proportional to $h$.